# I am having a issue while importing a module Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, face-detection

I am receiving below two errors while trying to run Firebase in my App:

Issue is raising in AppDelegate.swift while trying to import a Firebase.

```
Error 1: Could not build Objective-C module 'Firebase'
Error 2: 'FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h' file not found
```

This is my PodFile:

platform :ios, '13.0'

target 'eKYCDemo' do
use_frameworks!
pod 'Firebase/MLVision'
pod 'Firebase/MLVisionFaceModel'

Comment: hi @vinodsingh. Welcom to SO, next time be sure tu post your code snippet (should be a minimal reproducible example) instead of pasting an image this way you'll get more help:https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: post your error message too

Comment: Perhaps you overlooked this in the [Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#available-pods) *The Firebase iOS library Firebase/Core is no longer needed. This SDK included the Firebase SDK for Google Analytics*. Also, please include your podfile, a little snippet doesn't provide enough info.

Comment: Hi @jay, all the requirement are valid in my project, but I am getting these issues  while running on my simulator..

Comment: I think you are using old/outdated pods and API. See the new documentation for [ML Kit](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/migration). And note the pods in the file you're using are depreciated - here's the current pods [ML Kit Cocoapods](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/migration/ios#update_cocoapods). For example `MLVisionFaceModel` is now `GoogleMLKit/FaceDetection`

Answer (score 0):

1. Quit **Xcode**.
2. Delete project's temp files located at
   **~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData**
3. Delete **ProjectName.xcworkspace**
4. Delete **Podfile.lock** file and Pods folder
5. Run **pod install**.
6. Open **ProjectName.xcworkspace** file and build.